# How to assign an interface / type to a variable based on a condition in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to set the type / interface of a variable based on a condition. If possible I would like no reassignment of the variable.

comment1 for below code:

setting the type to `responseData: typeA | typeB = response.data` here results in
`Errormessage "Property 'specificBValue' does not exist on type 'typeA'.ts(2339)"`
or the other way around `Property 'specificAValue' does not exist on type 'typeB'`

```
interface typeA {
  name: string
  specificAValue: number
}

interface typeB {
  name: string
  specificBValue: string
}

const targetType = userInput.targetType;
axios.get(`/api?target=${targetType}`)
  .then(response => {
    const responseData = response.data; // comment1
    if(targetType === "A") {
      responseData: typeA
      console.log(responseData.specificAValue);
    } else if(targetType === "B") {
      responseData: typeB
      console.log(responseData.specificBValue);
    } else ...
```

Comment: Can you make it optional in both interfaces? specificAValue?: number;   specificBValue?: string;

Comment: hardly, i used a small example to not bloat the question. My actual interfaces have 31 and 14 Properties (in the second case one of those is an Array of Objects of another Interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a way to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) down the type of `responseData`. You can use type guards. See also [this](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard).

```
interface TypeA {
  name: string
  specificAValue: number
}

interface TypeB {
  name: string
  specificBValue: string
}

declare const responseData: unknown

const isUnknownRecord = (u: unknown): u is Record<string, unknown> => {
  const s = Object.prototype.toString.call(u)
  return s === '[object Object]' || s === '[object Window]'
}

const isString = (u: unknown): u is string => typeof u === 'string'

const isNumber = (u: unknown): u is number => typeof u === 'number'

const hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty

const isTypeA = (u: unknown): u is TypeA =>
  isUnknownRecord(u) &&
  hasOwnProperty.call(u, 'name') &&
  isString(u.name) &&
  hasOwnProperty.call(u, 'specificAValue') &&
  isNumber(u.specificAValue)


const isTypeB = (u: unknown): u is TypeB =>
  isUnknownRecord(u) &&
  hasOwnProperty.call(u, 'name') &&
  isString(u.name) &&
  hasOwnProperty.call(u, 'specificBValue') &&
  isString(u.specificBValue)

if (isTypeA(responseData)) {
  responseData // TypeA
} else if (isTypeB(responseData)) {
  responseData // TypeB
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECCyDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAObF3YLAzAI4BqcAGwCu1UkPIAjaIQC+hQqEixEKDNgBCBVmUo16jECxK12nbuv7DR+5rPkATCAgFwoKBAHsQ9ZG5NfaCAARODA4GiEQAGsQDwB3EHlPbzBkYFoAVWjYhIAlJw8oe2QAXmQACiEI7PiQAEoItNpkfM8igB4bQwAaZEiY2oA+UuGiEmSfZrKAeQkAKycwADpMKA8wdawIJY2AZQZmJYRBAUq61jcwISgQOlKSsoByAG0PecXkWYWEMABdR+QAB9AXcHk9Xu8fsgAOqgezxf52QgTVLpfYGJilCpVPo1BINPpNOgHQwjZBgLYeGCEsHIR5dJiPJIBVG0ABy4ikUCxlWqA3xjXSYkk0DJFOwVJpDzpIE50CZyJZyAAFnBaNMEgAFNbYKAUrFfRYrNYbcXbVXqrU66AU5kpJpqXA8nH9HL1QXNR14EqDVjpLL8kCtQr2M7IABk4dYFo1IG1Hl1FKOJ0qvUeOggjzqEajJDRJKYlSWGezkejatj8cT6GTAlOQjTJicZh4lhEWZzfvZcqgRabHC4rcEInOdp86UdmjKvNxgYJQiJk5GXYDbuDRTDZZIMatCZtNeOddTMoomdLuaa6OYRZLne3Fd31dr9cbpkHFmHZ7vl4Lfbf5jbCBR04CoJy2HByj8TAAmCUI4DqbMxl8CB-G8WCwmQAB6TC0HA2RkAgARAjSalyjAjRIJQ6C0JCMIEK0EgoJg2i4CwnDJzsIA)

I suggest you to not reinvent the wheel and use libraries like [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts).

Comment: Thank you for the io-ts library, i wasn't aware of this one.